# Using numpy.where() along with an or statement gives me back an error about ambiguous values

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am trying to select values from multiple arrays for a project, but am having trouble with the Boolean that goes along with it. I have two data files called "zdat" and "photdat" which have over 5000 values each. I need to sparse these down into a new array using quality flags from both. For the zdat file, I need the flags to be 3 OR 4, so I thought I could just plug this into a numpy.where function, but I keep getting the same error: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I have looked up what these do and have tried adding them into the code to allow me to use an OR statement, but I keep getting the error. The rest of the numpy.where function works without the or statement, but I need the or statement to select good quality data.

```py
izspec = np.where(np.any(zdat['spec_z'] == 3 or 4) & (photdat['totmask'] == 0) & (photdat['K_flag'] == 0) & (goodmag < 23))
```

I expect it to sparse down my data from around 5000 to around 170ish (I was told the amount of good data points). If I have it set to "zdat['spec_z'] == 3" or "zdat['spec_z'] == 4" then either one gives me around 60-80 points respectively, but each of those flags are considered "good" so I need both.

Comment: For one thing, look more closely at `np.any(zdat['spec_z'] == 3 or 4)`

Comment: I am confused on what I am supposed to be looking for. I want to select values from the zdat file in the column of 'spec_z' that are equal to 3 or 4

Comment: You are on the right track by creating a boolean array with those `(zdat..)&(photodat...}&(....)`.  Just split the that first `or` into two expressions joined with a `|`.  All the work is in getting that boolean right.  `np.where` just looks for the `True` values in the resulting boolean.

Comment: I believe that the way you’re using `np.where()` is unnecessary and [discouraged](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Just use `my_array[conditions]` if you want to select the values.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, the habit of using `np.where` when we mean `np.nonzero` will die slowly, if at all.  In any case that's not the problem here.  The issue is how to correctly construct the boolean array that includes the `or` condition.  Python evaluates that argument in full before even calling `where/nonzero`.  And as far as I know, there isn't any advantage to using the boolean indexing directly.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh yeah I know that’s not the issue, it was a general tip.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use boolean tests like this:

```py
(at['spec_z'] == 3 or 4) # BAD!
```

You need to repeat the test, like this:

```
(at['spec_z'] == 3 or at['spec_z'] == 4)
```

Or like this:

```
(at['spec_z'] in (3, 4))
```